# avoid open a popup in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

```
BEGIN
  RETURN '<script>if (confirm("¿Deseas abrir el Popup LOV?")) { apex.event.trigger($("#YOUR_BUTTON_ID"), "click"); } else { return false; }</script>';
END;
```

avoid open a popup in Oracle APEX using the tools o feacture avalibes in Oracle 11 and Apex 5

Comment: I don't follow the question.  You post code that opens a popup.  But you ask how you can avoid opening a popup.  The simple answer would be to not open the popup.  But I doubt that is what you are trying to ask